# how to connect 2 raspberry pi's via ethernet

Tags: python, ethernet, raspberry-pi4

I have 2 rpi and I want to connect them together via ethernet directly to exchange data between them. What's the simplest way to do it?

I tried using i2c communication but it was too noisy.

Answer (score 2):

Connect them using a [crossover cable](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet_crossover_cable). They will behave as two separate nodes in a local area network. Assign them unique class C static IPs like 192.168.1.1 and 192.168.1.2.

You can open a TCP socket and establish communication.

Comment: The nice thing about this option is that it is extensible -- you can move to 3 or 4 systems just by using an inexpensive Ethernet switch.

Comment: we did exactly that and we didn't have any progress

Comment: Can you provide more details of what you tried? This solution is a fundamental networking solution. It should be a slam dunk solution.

Comment: We have configured the dhcpcd.conf file giving eth0 static ip but nothing.
We have configured interfaces file giving eth0 a static ip there. Nothing again
We tried ping each other but nothing. We don't want anything to do with a router, only our two pi

Comment: You shouldn't use dhcp in this case.  Just manually set the network interfaces. Here is a link that might help do this. https://www.baeldung.com/linux/set-static-ip-address

Comment: we tried everything in this article and we have no progress with error : access denied